# How to UPDATE in database using mysqli prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using mysqli before to my query and now I convert it to mysqli prepared statements. I'm trying to update a particular data with upload image and I don't know why I get the error

> mysqli_stmt_bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in line 30

Also, how can I execute the query in mysqli query like `mysqli_query($conn, $query)`

Below is the code of my UPDATE query:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $imageName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_FILES["latest_photo"]["name"]);
    $imageData = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, file_get_contents($_FILES["latest_photo"]["tmp_name"]));
    $imageType = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_FILES["latest_photo"]["type"]);

        if (substr($imageType, 0,5) == "image") {

            $query = "UPDATE `crew_info` SET `updated_photo` = ? WHERE `id` = ?";
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $imageData, $_GET['id']);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $updated_photo);    

            //HOW CAN I EXECUTE THE QUERY HERE?
            echo "Image Uploaded";

        }

        else {

            echo "Image is not uploaded!";

        }

}
```

In the code above, there is a comment line on how to execute the query. How can I do that?

When I click the button Upload, it says that the image is uploaded but does not appear in the database. Why is that?

Comment: in my `mysqli_stmt_bind_result()`, I tried to include all the columns in that table.

Comment: you're running an update statement that doesn't return any results, which is why you can't bind to the result with `mysqli_stmt_bind_result`. if you want results returned, then you will need a 2nd statement, like `SELECT crew_info, updated_photo WHERE id = ?`

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to mysqli prepared

Comment: how can I execute a query in mysql_prepared @JeffPuckettII?

Comment: You already have executed the query. You need to *fetch* the rows. Btw.: You don't need to escape data inserted by prepared statements in `?` placeholders.

Comment: so there's nothing wrong in my code? there is only missing line of codes? right?

Comment: also there is another problem. check my edited post please. thank you

Comment: Looked closer... you have executed a DML, which will not give you any data except the number of rows affected. To get data from the table, you first have to execute an SQL query.

Comment: Since `UPDATE` statements do not have a result, there are no result fields to bind. Do a `SELECT` if you want a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For procedural way

```
$query = "UPDATE `crew_info` SET `updated_photo` = ? WHERE `id` = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
// you should use i instead of s for id
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'si', $imageData, $_GET['id']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Try this out in object-oriented style

```
$query = "UPDATE `crew_info` SET `updated_photo` = ? WHERE `id` = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("si", $imageData, $_GET['id']);
$stmt->execute();
```